# Could the [recommend*] tags be destroyed?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There are a couple of tags:

- [recommendation](/questions/tagged/recommendation) *343 questions*
- [recommendations](/questions/tagged/recommendations) *4 questions*
- <strike>[recommend](/questions/tagged/recommend) *2 questions*</strike>

which don't appear to generate useful content -- much like the recently noted [vague](/questions/tagged/vague), [speculative](/questions/tagged/speculative), & [future](/questions/tagged/future).  Also, several of the questions under:

- [product-recommendation](/questions/tagged/product-recommendation) *14 questions*

also appear to be off-topic.  However, some could be retagged using [recommendation-engine](/questions/tagged/recommendation-engine) which already has a nice tag wiki & doesn't have the implicit ambiguity of "product recommendation".

**Update:**

Perhaps the [recommend](/questions/tagged/recommend) tag should stick around for questions about Facebook's  [recommend] button.

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7228389/317773
- [Why is my Facebook [recommend] button getting cut off at bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5307456/317773)

Comment: I feel like *recommendations* is just a synonym for *opinions*...

Comment: It's also a meta tag. I *recommend* that it be destroyed.